# Help adding an Action in CiviRules

Tags: civirules

I trying to add an Action in CiviRules. I am trying to follow the [API add instructions](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/#adding-an-action-using-the-api).

Here is what I did
1. Copied the file org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesActions/Activity/UpdateStatus.php (this looked like an easy edit to do what I wanted--update a field) and created a new file in org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesActions/Contributions/UpdateInstallments.php

2. I edited the copied file (edits in bold)

`
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html
 */

**class CRM_CivirulesActions_Contribution_UpdateInstallments** extends CRM_CivirulesActions_Generic_Api {

/**
   * Method to get the api entity to process in this CiviRule action
   *
   * @access protected
   * @abstract
   */
  protected function getApiEntity() {
    return '**Contribution**';
  }`

But it does not show up in the Rules option list. I tried a cache clear. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation on how to add your own action here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/.

I would recommend reading the documentation, it will give you a better understanding of what is required. And then copy and adapt as much as you like :-)

If you do not see it in the list of actions it is because you have copied the class, but not added a record to the civirule_action table (from what you describe).

Comment: I had Inserted the action in civirules_action table by filling the fields. I deleted that row and did a SQL Insert query and then it worked.

Comment: glad it did :-)